# BootstrapValidator validations with dynamically added forms (not fields!)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm working on a page where a user can edit/delete or add addresses. For the form validation I use BootstrapValidatior and the form is saved via ajax call and if the data is saved another form is added to the DOM. Everything is working except if I'm working with newly added forms to the DOM (for example if I added an address and after that I want to edit the form doesn't validates).

I know this thing is called event delegation and I know the right way to handle this situations is firing event like:

```
$(document).on('click', '.deleteAddress', function () {});
```

But I don't know how to do this with BootstrapValidator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add the Bootstrap validation logic in the callback of the ajax call that adds the address form to the DOM.

E.g.

```
$(function() {
    $("#addFormButton").click(function() {
      $.getJSON("/dynamicform", function (data) {
          // Append form to the DOM
          $("#formDiv").append(data.dynamicForm);
          // Call Bootstrap Validator
          $("#formDiv form").bootstrapValidator();
      });
    });
});
```

[Plnkr example here](http://embed.plnkr.co/3MAEe85eXR8vNBkWDNyD/preview)